# C++ Image analyzing + pressing buttons

Tags: c++, image, bmp, poker

I have an idea to make a program that would analyze a running program, make a decision and push one of three buttons in that program.

I want to ask:

**A)** How should image analyzing work?

My idea is to take a screenshot of a window, find out where that program is ( *How?* ) and find out what cards do i have (Poker app) ( *How?* )

**B)** How another program can press buttons in specific area of the screen?

( I'm pretty new, so i want to learn by doing )

Thanks for any ideas or help!

I just don't know where to start after i take a screenshot. ( Got a JPG, but as i'm reading on stackoverflow bmps are better for image analyzing )

And yeah, i want to make a poker bot, odd counter and who knows what comes next to my mind. Not making it for cheating, i mean, i love poker, i don't want to cheat, i play it on my own without any bots, i just like to know how stuff works and now i want to try and make one on my own. Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand this, `My idea is to take a screenshot of a window, find out where that program is `

Comment: Sorry, but if you read the FAQ before posting you would have realised that this is not a suitable question to ask here.

Comment: You can take a look at this project: http://www.sikuli.org/ and see how they do.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely looking to develop a [**computer vision**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) application. I would recommend that you read first a bit about it and then start developing easier applications with [**OpenCV**](http://opencv.org/), the most used library to solve computer vision problems. In the webpage you can find many examples that may help you in developing your final application. Good luck!